# Find_or_initialize_by(nil) returns last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm trying to create a complicated(imo) CSV/Excel import process, which has to create records for 3 separate models + associations, and while debugging the validation for this process I have stumbled upon a confusing concept regarding `find_or_initialize_by()` when the passed attributes are **`nil`**.

According to [Rails API Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by), `find_or_initialize_by()` should do the following:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 222
  def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
    find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
  end
```

Which leads me to believe that if I pass attributes to `find_by` which are **`nil`** or even **`blank`** it should then move it to `Model.new(nil)`, however, for me it keeps returning the last record for that model.

Methods such as `Model.find_by()` and `Model.where().find_or_initialize` when passed `nil, {}, false, ""` still return the last record.

The reason I want it to initialize a `new` record with `nil` attributes is so that it fails validation and throws and error back to the user that the data entered in that row is invalid. (Since this is not a standard `columns = model attributes` type of import, I have to parse the passed columns through another method that should return `nil` if a piece of the entry is bad... at least thats the best way I can think of.)

So would anyone be able to help me understand why this doesn't work as I've explained and what your suggestion might be in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which leads me to believe that if I pass attributes to find_by which
>   are nil or even blank it should then move it to Model.new(nil),
>   however, for me it keeps returning the last record for that model.

No, that's not right. [`find_by()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) always return first record **matching the specified conditions**, in your case **there is no any conditions**, so first record is returned.

It is returns nil only **if conditions isn't matching**:

```
=> Model.find_by(nil)       # empty conditions without column specifying 
=> #<Model:0x00561654201c30
=> Model.find_by(foo: nil)  # empty conditions with column specifying
=> nil
```

In order to initialize model with empty atributes, use empty conditions:

```
=> Model.where(foo: nil, bar: nil).find_or_initialize
```

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I naturally thought `Model.where(nil)` would equate to `Model.where(foo: nil, bar: nil)`, so thank you for clearing that up! Do you know if there is anything **ensure** that something passed to `Model.where(foo: nil, bar: nil).find_or_initialize` would always return a nil object in the extremely unlikely event that a record were to be persisted with nil attributes, passed validations and such, aka a failsafe of sorts?

Comment: The one thing in my mind, it's write a custom method, which just a wrapper around `where(foo: nil, bar: nil).find_or_initialize` calling, whom checks parameters before passing it to the `where(foo: nil, bar: nil).find_or_initialize`, that method can for example initialize model `Model.new(attr)` and check if it's valid `Model.new(attr).valid?`, to avoid unexpected database writing. Also take a look at [Keyword Arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) it has a very strict behaviour for arguments.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing for this process.. or at least trying to. I'm getting a `undefined method 'find_or_initialize' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> Did you mean? find_or_initialize_by first_or_initialize` when calling it from `newprop = Property.where(address1: nil, city: nil).find_or_initialize`, I swapped out what I actually have in my `where clause` to ensure that it wasn't my custom method which should be returning a hash of nil attributes based on a condition. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a little vague for me. But did you try to remove `where` closure and just use `Property.find_or_initialize_by(address1: nil, city: nil) { |record| check here if you record persisted }`.

Comment: I initially had it as `newprop = Property.find_or_initialize_by(address: nil, city:nil)` but that continues to load the existing properties for some reason so I changed it to the way you suggested in your answer. I have my validations in another method so the process is to check all imported rows first, using 1000 in my csv file with a couple bad records in it for testing, then after it `initializes` all the records, it checks if they are valid before saving. Everything works fine if all 1000 pass validations, the validations catch invalid data for the other models but not the `Property` one.

Comment: Is it about your case https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26618 ? I'm sorry it's really hard to me to diagnose problem without a code. I suggest you to ask one another question with validations problem.

Comment: No, I have this process set up in such a way that I'm manually placing the ID into the child model to be safe, i.e. `Order.new(property_id: newprop.id, ...)` instead of `order.property.build`. That's how I traced it back to spawn my original post, when it goes to create `Orders` for the 1000 `Property`, the `Order` validations fail stating no properties exist, but I need the `Property` validation to fail first to state something like "Please check the address entered on line `X`".

Comment: How about custom validation? may be the active record hooks ? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks can help you to check the parent model.

Comment: Would you be opposed to moving this to a quick chat so that I can give you a clearer understanding of what I mean? To me my process makes sense and is hinging on the `find_or_initialize` part that we've discussed earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154749/discussion-between--and-cdouble-bhuck).